# Crash on start qt 5.15 app(armv8a build) in Android 5.1

Tags: android, qt, android-5.1.1-lollipop, qt5.15

The last message before crash in the log:

> LOGCAT: F/art     (22502): art/runtime/mirror/art_method.cc:356] Check
> failed: !IsFastNative() int java.lang.Character.digitImpl!(int, int)

...and I have no clue what does this function check.

The source code available here(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/refs/tags/android-cts-5.1_r21/runtime/mirror/art_method.h)

```
bool IsFastNative() SHARED_LOCKS_REQUIRED(Locks::mutator_lock_)
{
  uint32_t mask = kAccFastNative | kAccNative;
  return (GetAccessFlags() & mask) == mask;
}
```

- Same app, armv7a build runs like a charm
- Same app, armv8a build, Android 10 runs like a charm as well.

What can be the reason? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I have the same with QT 5.15.2

Comment: @Dmitriano, was fixed in 5.15.3 but you can try apply the patch by your own (see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-84849?focusedCommentId=530372&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-530372)

Comment: Applied the patch, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is happening because of a bug in the latest qt 5.15.0

Fresh issues:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85493

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-84849